# FBSDKLoginKit breaks after pods installation

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

After installing `FBSDKLoginKit` through CocoaPods, I get the build errors

> No known class method for selector 'areAllPermissionsReadPermissions:'
>
> No known class method for selector 'areAllPermissionsPublishPermissions:'

both located in `/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.m`.
`FBSDKCoreKit` is also installed through CocoaPods.

What I have checked is the following:

- FBSDKLoginKit does get added to the frameworks folder
- It has the correct target membership
- It is included in `Link Binary With Libraries`
- I can import `FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h`
  without getting an error

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What is the code where you are getting the issues? If those are the only two errors, it could just be a version difference.

Comment: I encounter this error after updating FBSDKLoginKit from 4.7.0 to 4.10.0. Downgrade FBSDKLoginKit to 4.7.0 fix this for me. Maybe you can try to integrate lower version FBSDKLoginKit. Maybe the cause is inconsistent version of facebook SDKs?

Comment: @EgistLi I am facing same error I have Downgrade FBSDKLoginKit to 4.7.0 but showing same error. In fact it deletes pods from pod folder from my project

Comment: @Daniel Are you able to solve your issue? Please help me

Comment: @jalakpatel check my answer. And Egist, thank you for the hint

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Egist was right, my problem was inconsistent versions of the different SDKs.
My Podfile specified

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

and for some reason, this resulted in these frameworks being installed:

```
FBSDKCoreKit  - 4.8.0
FBSDKLoginKit - 4.10.0
```

Obviously, the way out of this was to specify the versions:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.10.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.10.0'
```

Comment: Happend to me also. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I upgraded to cocoapods rc3 and it installed both frameworks to correct version, but the sharekit got messed up instead and i had to manually specify its version.